# How to get Corda transaction time?

Tags: corda

I am using the following to get the transaction timestamp:

```
    val outputStateRef = StateRef(ledgerTx.id, 0)
    val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(stateRefs = listOf(outputStateRef))
    val results = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<ContractState>(queryCriteria)
    val recordedTime = results.statesMetadata.singleOrNull()?.recordedTime
```

The problem is the transaction time is not always returned, sometimes null is returned for the timestamp.

Why is this happening and how can I ensure the timestamp is always returned?

Answer (score 0):

`results` is `Vault.Page<ContractState>` which contains the following variables:

```
    /**
     * Returned in queries [VaultService.queryBy] and [VaultService.trackBy].
     * A Page contains:
     *  1) a [List] of actual [StateAndRef] requested by the specified [QueryCriteria] to a maximum of [MAX_PAGE_SIZE].
     *  2) a [List] of associated [Vault.StateMetadata], one per [StateAndRef] result.
     *  3) a total number of states that met the given [QueryCriteria] if a [PageSpecification] was provided,
     *     otherwise it defaults to -1.
     *  4) Status types used in this query: [StateStatus.UNCONSUMED], [StateStatus.CONSUMED], [StateStatus.ALL].
     *  5) Other results as a [List] of any type (eg. aggregate function results with/without group by).
     *
     *  Note: currently otherResults are used only for Aggregate Functions (in which case, the states and statesMetadata
     *  results will be empty).
     */
```

As it looks from your code, if result page contains multiple `StateAndRef`, the method code `singleOrNull()?` will actually return null.

This is my guess based on available codes, please share more information if this wasnt the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would add your own timestamp to the state and record it in the flow.

Or, you can add a Time-Window to the transaction (https://docs.corda.net/api-transactions.html#time-windows).  I believe this also ensures that the statesMetadata.recordedTime will not be null.